# Customizing autogenerated partial classes

Tags: c#, partial-classes

I have autogenerated partial classes like:

```
public partial class MyEntity { ... }
```

I use `MyEntity.partial.cs` file to extend the partial class. I want to avoid situation where autogenerated MyEntity disappears or is renamed but the customized MyEntity.partial.cs stays and compiles without errors.

How to ensure that I can extend only existing partial classes?

Comment: Why not proof this when generating classes? Or do i misunderstand your question? Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: are the filenames same?

Comment: @BendEg: I'm generating the classes from XSD schema. How to prove, when generating, that there is no other handwritten partial class?

Comment: @Nikita: no, usually all the generated classes are in single file due to easier source control

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure there exists any *good* solution to this.

Here is *a* solution.

Have your auto-generated classes contain the following:

```
partial void CompileTimeCheckThatAutoGeneratedPartExists();
```

Then write in each of your hand-written extensions:

```
partial void CompileTimeCheckThatAutoGeneratedPartExists()
{
}
```

Note: The body in the auto-generated part is a semicolon `;` while the body in your extension part is an empty block `{ }`.

When ever the auto-generated part disappears, is renamed or moved to another `namespace`, a compile-time error will occur.